# Accessing hostname when traffic passed through AWS Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, load-balancing, amazon-elb

For our application we are using AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB) and have a listener for HTTP: 80 to forward traffic to the TargetGroup.

The way we have setup our application is that we will have a number subdomains and need to access these original subdomains (companyA.something.com) from within the application. Currently the application sees the DNS name of the ALB itself.

So far I have tried to setup the subdomain (in Route53) a couple ways:

1. Created subdomain as A record with ALIAS pointing to the ALB DNS
   Name
2. Created Hosted Zone for subdomain adding NS records for the
   subdomain to the zone file for the parent domain
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html

*I discovered that these are basically the same and the application still sees only the ALB DNS Name.*

**Is there anyway for me to get the original subdomain my users are going to without overriding with the ALB DNS name?**

Thanks in advance,
Aaron

Comment: It should already be working the way you need for it to.  An ALB's hostname should only be visible to the application if that's also the hostname showing in your browser's address bar.  You're not using anything not mentioned, like CloudFront (or Cloudflare), right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the [HTTP HOST header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host). The framework you use should already be able to handle it for you.

Comment: yes this is precisely what I'm doing. I am using Sails.js framework  and get the header (http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-headers )however it is showing the full DNS name from the ALB not companyA.something.com

Comment: @Aaron Well, that means you're trying to access the application by the ALB dns name not by the domain name you want. ALB won't change the headers. So how are you calling it?

Comment: This is the correct answer. curl --header "Host: bla.bla.com:8443"  "http://localhost:8080/" results on HttpServletRequest::getServerName() giving back `bla.bla.com`